# VueJS: How to toggle dropdown menu when new View is loaded?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, view, navigation

I'm new to VueJS. I've worked with a static CSS framework for many years but I would like to learn more about VueJS. I have the following navigation code. The problem is that the dropdown menu is still visible if I load a new page. How do I need to adjust the JS code so that the dropdown menu also collapses when a new View is loaded via VueJS? I've tried a few things with methods under export default but nothing worked for me.

I'm using Vue 2.6.11.

Thanks for your help! :)

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'load',
  function() {
    let hamburgerMenu = document.getElementById('hamburger-menu')

    hamburgerMenu.addEventListener(
      'click',
      function() {
        hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle('is-active')

        let navigation = document.getElementById('navigation')
        navigation.classList.toggle('hamburger-toggle-nav-display-block')
        hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle('z-index-9999')
      },
      false
    )
  },
  false
)
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/projekte">Projekte</router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/projekte/einzelprojekt">Einzelprojekt</router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/kontakt">Kontakt</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button
      class="hamburger hamburger--collapse"
      type="button"
      id="hamburger-menu"
    >
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="hamburger-label">Menü</span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please add a sandbox link to this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, will it help to upload the final build to a Domain or do you need the production files?

Comment: I need to see the demo of above behaviour. For that I will need a demo link like this https://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/srNVQ/


One thing I can tell your from your code is you don't need to get every document element using document.getElementByID,
you can check for refs, https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html
It's like you are not taking the advantage of vuejs features.